# install passport for laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

- laravel/passport v6.0.7 requires php >=7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.

  - laravel/passport v6.0.6 requires php >=7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/passport v6.0.5 requires php >=7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/passport v6.0.4 requires php >=7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/passport v6.0.3 requires php >=7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.5 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.11 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.10 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.7.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.5 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.38 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.37 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.36 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.35 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.34 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.33 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.32 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.31 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.30 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.29 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.28 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.27 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.26 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.25 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.24 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.23 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.22 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.21 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.20 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.19 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.17 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.16 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.15 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.14 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.13 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.12 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.11 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.10 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - illuminate/contracts v5.6.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - Installation request for laravel/passport ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.0.5, v6.0.6, v6.0.7].

Comment: Oh It seems laravel passport v6.0.7 needs php greater than v7.1 .
So either you can upgrade php version on reduce the passport vesion.
Which can resolve the issue. to reduce passport version try this version `composer require laravel/passport "4.*"` or upgradi your laravel to 5.6 or 5.7 may also help

Answer (score 2):

I did the following to fix the installation at the moment:

```
composer require paragonie/random_compat:2.*
composer require laravel/passport "4.0.*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install compatible version of laravel 5.5 with the following command.

```
composer require laravel/passport "4.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the option with the composer to forcefully install package.

Define all package dependency in `composer.json` file from the root directory of the project, then execute the command

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```